# coldfusion session variable not defined

Tags: session, coldfusion

Ive been monitoring the log files of my application recently and its got quite a few references of a certain session variable apparently not existing.

I Know its been defined, as its been part of the application since we built the very first version around 4 or 5 years ago.

So what Im wondering is... if CF throws an error stating that the session variable is undefined. is this an example of a race condition in CF ?

Or is there any other thing that could be causing this generally ?

The session variable is defined when the user logs in as part of their login credentials using a struct containing the users profile information.

At the point of adding an item to the users shopping cart, we must leverage a particular key of this struct to post to a legacy system.

From time to time we see that this variable is not defined. Which is really strange as its definitely there because if it wasnt, the struct that it resides in wouldnt exist.

This application is an application that has been migrated from CF 8 to CF10 and it could be the reason as to the cause of the issue.

Comment: It's impossible to say anything sensible about this on the basis of the info provided. Where is the variable defined? It sounds to me like the session is timing out, and you're making assumptions as to the logical around the variable's lifetime. What troubleshooting steps have you engaged in, thusfar?

Comment: Have you migrated in your application recently from CF8 to CF9/CF10? I have seen lot of issues related to sessions after this upgrade. Reason being behavioral change in how OnRequestEnd gets called and other issue is cflocation can not maintain sessions.

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2221-cfabort-and-onrequestend-behavior-in-coldfusion-8-and-coldfusion-9.htm, and comments in this post can help understand the issue. But this is just plain guess as Adam already said, it is very difficult to gauge from the info provided.